# Node.js: How to throttle a list of requests?

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-403, throttling, node-async

I'm writing a node.js app which needs to get some data from a list of pages from a provider:

```
var list = [
  { url: 'http://www.example.com/1' },
  { url: 'http://www.example.com/2' },
  ...
  { url: 'http://www.example.com/N' },
];
```

Currently I'm using [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async), which works nicely:

```
async.each(
  list, // 1st param is the array of items
  function(elem, callback) { // 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
    request(elem.url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
      }
    }),
  },
  function(err) { // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error in the final async callback:', err);
    }
  }
);
```

The only problem is that the site's server some times (understandably) responds with a *403* (*forbidden*) status code, due to an excess of requests from the same IP in the time unit...

I see `async` provides a `whilst()` method, too, whose example is:

```
var count = 0;
async.whilst(
  function () { return count < 5; },
  function (callback) {
    count++;
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
  },
  function (err) {
    // 5 seconds have passed
  }
);
```

But I don't see how to use it to use it with a list, or how to use it combined with `async.each`... :-(

So the answer is: *How do I limit (throttle) a list of async requests in node.js?*

*P.S.:* To be clearer, I don't want (if possible) to *queue* the requests, since a request could possibly take a long time to complete...: I just want the requests to be *initiated* at defined temporal intervals (say 5 ~ 10 seconds between each request...).

---

**UPDATE:**

After alireza david comment, I did try using async.eachLimit, which looked very promising, to me... This is an example of it's usage, on the module github [site](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js):

```
async.eachLimit(
    obj.files,
    limit
    function (file, complete) {
      complete();
    },
    function (err) {
    }
);
```

But the limit usage is not documented, and it's not clear to me...
If anybody has any clue...

Comment: The github link 404's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time 403 means you should limit your requests, Because web server thinks you doing DDOS attack.

In this situation you should `async.eachLimit()`

```
async.eachLimit(obj.files, 1000,
    function (file, complete) {
      complete();
    },
    function (err) {

    });
```

**UPDATE**
I think got it, The `limit` options is number of concurrence requests.
You should decrease this number (My opinion is 2 or 3 just for test)

Comment: Yessss. This is the solution! Thanks. Unfortunately on caolan/async page it's documented very poorly... Do you know of other sources of docs about it, or I'd better go to the source code?

Comment: No, sorry... It doesn't work for me... I don't understand what I should put in `limit` param... I did try with "milliseconds" (a value of 5000), but no limiting shown. I did try with "number of simultaneous iterations", but no limiting shown, either... I did peek at the code (https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js), but it's not so clear for me, either... :-(

Comment: Please open this link https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/test/test-async.js#L1482-1494 
This is test for eachLimit function.

Comment: Thanks... But that does not clarify how to use it :-(

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake when trying with value `1` :-( ... However, I don't know if it is what I was looking for: I'd better like to call functions in list with a defined time wait among each async call... Each call will possibly take a much longer time to complete than the time limit I want to set among the calls... With eachLimit(), I have to use the value `1` for the limit, but if some calls are fast, then the following functions will be called way too early, crashing my system... :-(